# Import x and y coordinates from .txt file

Tags: c#, coordinates

I need to read coordinates from text file for my project,but the text file is like this

```
1 37.4393516691 541.2090699418

2 612.1759508571 494.3166877396

3 38.1312338227 353.1484581781
```

and with more space in front.I have code that i tried but i couldn't make the seperators work.

```
      1    1150.0  1760.0

      2     630.0  1660.0

      3      40.0  2090.0
```

The code:

```
 string[] cityPositions = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
                foreach (string cityP in cityPositions)
                {
                    int startIndexX = cityP.IndexOf("  ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 3;
                    int endIndexX = cityP.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                    int X = int.Parse(cityP.Substring(startIndexX, endIndexX - startIndexX));

                    int startIndexY = cityP.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 3;
                    int endIndexY = cityP.IndexOf("", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                    int Y = int.Parse(cityP.Substring(startIndexY, endIndexY - startIndexY));
                    create_City(new Point(X, Y));
                }
```

Comment: You could loop through each string character by character, each time ignoring the spaces, the first number being an index, second and third numbers being the co-ordinate values you are interested in.
Or, you could make use of Regular Expressions to extract the numbers only

Comment: Would be much more safer with regular expressions, Try `var cords = Regex.Split(cityP, @"\s");`  the `\s` matches all spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make use of Regular Expressions, try this:

```
        String expression = @"(\d)([\d\.]*)([\d\.]*)";

        Regex r = new Regex(expression);

        foreach (String cityPosition in cityPositions)
        {
            MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(cityPosition);
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(mc[0].Value);
            decimal coOrdX = Convert.ToDecimal(mc[1].Value);
            decimal coOrdY = Convert.ToDecimal(mc[2].Value);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", index, coOrdX, coOrdY));
        }
```

This code will produce this output:

```
1 1150.0 1760.0
2 630.0 1660.0
3 40.0 2090.0
```

It should disregard the varying amount of space between the values and make it easier to parse the three different values in the file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your data type doesnt match. You should use double for coordinates, and use Split method, for example:

```
double X = double.Parse(cityP.Split()[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double Y = double.Parse(cityP.Split()[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Split function with no parameters given will split by whitespace.

**EDIT**

It's not clear in the question but, if your lines dont have the same pattern, and have different spaces use Split method like this:

```
double X = double.Parse(cityP.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with indices, you could Replace multiple whitespaces with a single whitespace, like

```
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
    Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);     
    cityP = regex.Replace(cityP, " ");
```

then use split to get the coordinates

```
    var x = double.Parse(cityP.Split()[1]);
    var y = double.Parse(cityP.Split()[2]);
```